# Android Caching Files vs Downloading

Tags: android, caching, file-management

In my Travel app which depends on lot of images. I have implemented a Lazy Loader and Caching of images. In total for all the destinations the images are close to 20mb. If a User wants to download all the Images so that he can still access the app offline. How can i make sure the caching of the files work with the downloaded image files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two possibilities for your app, depending on what exactly you are wanting to do. Feel free to read more about this at the [Android Docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal).

**Internal Storage**

This directory persists, and is private to your application. It might have limited space, especially for older devices.

**SD Card**

This will have much more space, but will be accessible to the user and other apps. You could store information in your private storage to verify the integrity of this data. You will need a permission to write to the card.

I would suggest you choose one of these two, and store your data there. This should persist from run to run. Perhaps you could even include a function that would "Pre-cache" all of the files to the appropriate folder. 20 Mb isn't really that much space, you could even include it in your app itself. It's all up to you.

Comment: what i meant to ask is - i want to store the content in the SD card. But how can i handle two instances 1. The User wants to download data as and when he uses the app and the caching happens. 2. When they user Says i want to download all the images so that it will work with out the internet connection as well

Comment: There are a few ways. I would have each file be listed by name, and try to get it first on the SD card, then the internet. Should be straightforward from there.